# Performance of ON DELETE CASCADE in PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization, cascade

I have an issue related to performance of ON DELETE CASCADE. I'm trying to understand why it takes so long. For this topic purposes I simplified real case to schema presented below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.items
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT items_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.links
(
    parent uuid,
    child uuid,
    CONSTRAINT links_parent_fk FOREIGN KEY (parent)
        REFERENCES public.items (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT links_child_fk FOREIGN KEY (child)
        REFERENCES public.items (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS parent_idx
    ON public.links USING btree
    (parent ASC NULLS LAST);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS child_idx
    ON public.links USING btree
    (child ASC NULLS LAST);
    
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```

and data can be generated with:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.items
   SELECT uuid_generate_v4 (), 'item_' || i
   FROM generate_series(1, 134001) AS i;
   
INSERT INTO links
   SELECT (SELECT id FROM public.items WHERE name='item_1'), id FROM public.items;
```

Briefly, data base contains two tables. Table `items` contains a list of items (identifier and name column) and table `links` which defines relations between items (parent <-> child). In presented case all items (children) belongs to item named 'item_1' (parent).

I call a query in order to delete all children assigned to parent:

```sql
BEGIN;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE DELETE FROM public.items where id in (SELECT child FROM public.links WHERE parent = (SELECT id FROM public.items WHERE name='item_1'));
ROLLBACK;
```

From execution plan we can read among others:
"Trigger for constraint links_parent_fk: time=10451.471 calls=134001"
"Trigger for constraint links_child_fk: time=2962.035 calls=134001"

The question is why trigger for constraint `links_parent_fk` consumes a lot time?

I performed some attempts with exchanging data between columns in `links` table. After that trigger for `links_child_fk` consumed ~10 s and trigger for `links_parent_fk` took ~3 s. I'm curious why there is such difference between execution of this delete cascades?

**PostgreSQL version: 12.4 and 13.9.**

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: Checked on PostgreSQL version 12.4 and 13.9.

Comment: What is your OS, and what is your hardware like?  I can't reproduce this poor performance, getting results over 5 times faster.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in the topic. In my both development environments Windows 10 is installed. First machine on which I run benchmark is virtual machine (vSphere, 8 GB RAM). The second one is laptop (Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4310U, 8 GB RAM, SSD). I'm getting simillar result on both machines. Your results are very interesting. Are there huge differences between our hardware and software specs? Did you notice also disproportion between trigger execution for links_child_fk and links_parent_fk like me?

Comment: On Windows 11 (ASUS x415 laptop, PostgreSQL v14 as I don't have v13 installed there) it is much slower than on Linux and somewhat unstable, but still the longest was 4 seconds, with each trigger being about 2 seconds.  On Linux, (Virtual Box, running on the before-mentioned Windows 11 as the host), the trigger timings were also about equal at about 0.8 seconds.  I don't know how to profile code on Windows, so there isn't much more I can do there.

Answer (score 0):

> PostgreSQL will definitely run faster on Linux than on Windows (and I
> say this as one of the guys who wrote the windows port of it..) It is
> designed for a Unix style architecture, and implements this same
> architecture on Windows, which means it does a number of things that
> Windows isn't designed to do well. It works fine, but it doesn't
> perform as well.
>
> Magnus Hagander

https://www.postgresql.eu/events/pgconfeu2019/sessions/session/2664/slides/211/PostgreSQL%20under%20Windows.pdf

I've seen this first hand in the use of Postgres on Azure which, at the time, was windows postgres. I think they've moved / are moving to Linux postgres because of performance issues.

As a result of this, I think that performance testing Postgres on windows and running Postgres on windows in situations where performance is important doesn't make sense, better to use a different OS or a different RDBMS.